# How do I dynamically generate table rows without jquery?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table

Currently, I have a table class as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import "./Table.css";

export default function Table({theadData, tbodyData}) {
  return (
    <>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>2017</th>
        </tr>
        {Array.from(theadData).forEach(heading => {
            <tr>
              <td class="largeHeader" key={heading}>{heading}</td>
              <td class="primaryCell">{tbodyData[heading].value}</td>
            </tr>;
        })}
      </table>
    </>
  );
}
```

When I add console.log(heading) or console.log(tbodyData[heading].value) within the loop, I can see that they give the expected values. However, none of the rows are added on. Why is that and how can I solve this problem? (I'd prefer to avoid jquery and libraries of that nature if possible, but am open to ideas.)

Comment: "Why is that" - because `.forEach` does not do what you think it does. You want `.map` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several mistakes you made:

1. change `forEach` to `map`
2. replace `{}` with `()`, or add `return` before `<tr>`
3. put `key` on the root element which is `<tr>`

```js
{Array.from(theadData).map(heading => (
   <tr key={heading}>
     <td className="largeHeader">{heading}</td>
     <td className="primaryCell">{tbodyData[heading].value}</td>
   </tr>
))}
```

Comment: I'm not a React user, so forgive my ignorance - but I assume that `key=""` attribute values have to be unique in their context, right? So what happens if duplicate `heading` values end-up being used here?

Comment: It could produce some potential bugs when you add/remove elements from `theadData`. A common workaround is to also associate indexes to the `key`, such as `.map((heading, index) => <tr key={heading + index}>`.